# Использование mixin'ов из Bootstrap.less, как правильно?

Tags: bootstrap, css

Пару дней назад наткнулся на [LessCSS](http://lesscss.org/) и оооочень понравился подход, при котором не нужно прописывать по сотне раз одни и те же стили разным классам, а можно их мешать между собой, посредством mixin'ов и общих переменных. Как оказалось, исходники twitter bootstrap тоже написаны при помощи Less. Решил использовать все это в новом проекте.

Я хочу использовать twitter bootstrap и писать код вида:

```
    <div class="topinfo">
        <div class="logo">Logo</div>
        <div class="banner">banner</div>
        <div class="contacts">Contacts</div>
    </div>
```

а не

```
    <div class="row-fluid well well-small text-center">
        <div class="span4 well well-small">Logo</div>
        <div class="span4 well well-small">banner</div>
        <div class="span4 well well-small">Contacts</div>
    </div>
```

Первый вариант поидее реализуется посредством LessCSS, во втором же просто подключение "bootsrap.css".
С LessCss все выглядит более информативно , легче поддерживать и дополнять такой код, брать из bootstrap только нужное.

```
.topinfo {
  .row-fluid;
}
.logo {
  .text-center
  .span2;
  .well;
  .well-small;
}
...
```

Однако проблема в том , что у меня не получается правильно подключить LESS исходники Bootstrap'a. Я создаю файл layout.less , где подключаю bootstrap.less (вроде как главный файл, импортирующий все остальные) и пишу остальные стили. На данном этапе мне нужен только грид из фрэймворка, но он нифига не работает. Пробовал и импортировать отдельные файлы в свой layout.less и целиком - все равно половина классов не импортируется ((

Подключаю все это дело так:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="less/layout.less"/>
<script src="js/less-1.3.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

layout.less выглядит так:

```
@import "bootstrap/bootstrap.less";
... вышеуказанные стили ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько мне понятно из [документации](http://bootstrap.lesscss.ru/less.html#mixins), mixins должны использоваться так:

```
.topinfo {
    .row-fluid();
 }
```

Может в этом дело?

Comment: .row-fluid() - там такого нет миксина, но есть вроде для создания столбцов - makeColumn. Однако создается не адаптивный грид, а фиксированный. пока непонятно как сделать адаптивный...